# Is it recommended to use answers to post long comments?

Tags: discussion

I often find useful to write very long comment, typically when a question contains several issues of semantic that cannot be addressed with 600 characters (or even 1200 or 1800 characters). In such case, I can think of several possibilities:

1. Write many comments

   - The issue here is that it is impossible (or not easy) to write comment with an attractive format.
2. Talk to the user in a chat room

   - I am personally not very active on chat rooms and it is not here an instinctive solution for me. Also the issue of chat rooms is that it is likely future users will miss the discussion and will just repeat the same job. Also chatting diminish the advantage of delayed communication which I find typically useful when in need to offer a very clear semantic to an OP that will eventually disagree.
3. Write the long comment in an answer and clearly specify that is it nothing more than a long comment

   - This is here my favourite solution. Every user will see edit and it allows for faster reaction and more thoughtful close votes.

**What are you recommendations? How should one express an advanced / long comment?**

I recently used the third solution [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/51232/why-do-modern-humans-have-genetic-diseases/51238#51238) but it seems that @kmm disagreed with my methodology. I would appreciate advice on this specific case study as well.

Comment: The comment you referenced in your question at the end seems to have disappeared...

Comment: It has been deleted by @WYSIWYG indeed.

Comment: @Remi.b this question really IS a dupe, as WYSIWYG noted. I'm going to VTC this, and I'll answer over there.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate. I am voting to close as such. Thanks

Comment: I didn't delete the comment. It was autodeleted after you accepted the post as duplicate.